# Windows Form Tabs switching

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three tabs in a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) tab control. Currently in Tab1 I have a button that saves the information in a textbox and automatically changes the tabcontrol.SelectedIndex to Tab2. Tab2 then uses the information saved from tab1's textbox.

I want a messagebox to popup whenever the user changes the textbox in tab1, but then manually clicks tab2 or tab3 without hitting the button to save the information.

So in summary, I have it so clicking a button on tab1 automatically sends it to tab2. I want a messagebox to pop up if the button on tab1 is not pressed when the information was changed and the user manually changed the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a wizard-like design for your application is more appropriate. Tabs are not supposed to work like that from a user's perspective.

But a workaround for your current situation is:

- declare a variable, for example `dirty`
- set this variable whenever any control in tab1 has been edited
- clear the variable if the button in tab1 is clicked
- check this if tab2 or tab3 is selected

Comment: thank you, this work around is probably the best solution for now.  I realize that doing this isn't exactly what tabs were made for.  In the future I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Deselecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.deselecting.aspx) event on the TabControl to be informed when the selected tab is changing.  If the tab that is being deselected is the tab with the button on it and the information is not saved, you can display the message box.

Also, depending on what your program does, it may make more sense to go ahead and save the information when the tab changes without even bothering the user.

Comment: This will still fire when the button is clicked.

Comment: @jmccarthy: I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Your original answer said use the SelectedIndexChanged event but this fires when the SelectedIndex property changes on the tab control. I'm assuming the OP is changing this property when the button is clicked, which would fire this event. The OP wants the MessageBox to show only when the button is not clicked, so that wouldn't work. You have since changed your answer however, so my first comment is void.

Comment: @jmccarthy: oh...that makes more sense now.  I had forgotten the OP makes the button click send the user to tab 2.

Comment: I am thinking that maybe if I need to save it automatically I can have the pop-up notify that changes have been saved every time the tab1 is deselected.  Thanks